# Insert and update multiple rows into the MSSQL database based on the retrieved list

Tags: c#, sql, blazor

I have a method that adds a record to the table and updates the table based on the variables.

```
 public void UPDATEWM(string indeks, decimal ilosc, string osoba, string komu, decimal ile,int mag)
 {
     using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(con))
     {

         okucia_magazyn okucie = new okucia_magazyn();
         string sqlo = "  SELECT m.indeks,m.nazwa,m.jednostka, p.ilosc,p.regal,p.polka,p.uwagi,m.gid_numer,m.data_zalozenia FROM okucia_magazyn m JOIN mg_okucia_polozenie p ON p.gid_numer = m.gid_numer WHERE m.indeks LIKE '" + indeks + "' AND p.magazyn ="+mag+"";
         var cmdd = new SqlCommand(sqlo, con1);
         con1.Open();
         SqlDataReader rdrr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
         while (rdrr.Read())
         {
             okucie = new okucia_magazyn();
             okucie.indeks = rdrr[0].ToString();
             okucie.nazwa = rdrr[1].ToString();
             okucie.jednostka = rdrr[2].ToString();
             okucie.ilosc = Convert.ToDecimal(rdrr[3].ToString());
             okucie.regal = rdrr[4].ToString();
             okucie.polka = Convert.ToInt32(rdrr[5].ToString());
             okucie.uwagi = rdrr[6].ToString();
             okucie.gid_numer = Convert.ToInt32(rdrr[7].ToString());
             okucie.data_zalozenia = Convert.ToDateTime(rdrr[8].ToString());
         }
         con1.Close();
         con1.Open();


         string histsql = "INSERT INTO history_mg (indeks,nazwa,jednostka,data_lastmodf,ilosc,regal,polka,stan,uwagi,magazyn,gid_numer,data_dodania,data_usuniecia,osoba,komu) VALUES (@indeks, @nazwa, @jednostka,@data_lastmodf,@ilosc,@regal,@polka,@stan,@uwagi,@magazyn,@gid_numer,@data_dodania,@data_usuniecia,@osoba,@komu)";
         var hsql = new SqlCommand(histsql, con1);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indeks", indeks);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwa", okucie.nazwa);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jednostka", okucie.jednostka);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_lastmodf", DateTime.Now);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilosc", ile);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regal", okucie.regal);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@polka", okucie.polka);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stan", 3); //3 - Wydanie 4 - Przyjecie
         if (okucie.uwagi is null)
             okucie.uwagi = "";
         else
         {
             hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uwagi", okucie.uwagi);
         }
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@magazyn", mag);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gid_numer", okucie.gid_numer);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_dodania", okucie.data_zalozenia);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_usuniecia", "");
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@osoba", osoba);
         hsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@komu", komu);
         hsql.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con1.Close();
         con1.Open();
         string updateIlosc = "UPDATE mg_okucia_polozenie SET ilosc =@ilosc WHERE gid_numer=" + okucie.gid_numer+"AND magazyn ="+mag+" ";
         var usql = new SqlCommand(updateIlosc, con1);
         usql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilosc", ilosc);
         usql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gid_numer", okucie.gid_numer);
         usql.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con1.Close();

     }
 }
```

Now the problem is how to add and update rows in the table based on the list of items downloaded that the user creates himself?
Should I throw this into some loop?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking for advice? Ofcourse you should make a loop for a collection of items you are iterating over. If anything I would look into creating a data access layer for your application. This way you aren't handling all these repetitive database actions for every transaction. Look into Dapper or Entity framework Core.

Comment: also, you make people twitch when you do things like `WHERE gid_numer=" + okucie.gid_numer+"AND magazyn ="+mag+" ";` - you should use parameters for those bits, too; great work on the other parameters, though! (although you probably want to add a `@uwagi` even if it *is* `null` (send `DbNulll.Value` as the `.Value` in that case))

Comment: @TeunKruijer it isn't *quite* an "of course" - it *is* possible to send the data in a single chunk via a TVP, suitable for use with `MERGE`, but... that's quite an advanced usage; unless you *really really* care about the throughput, a loop of `insert`/`update` is going to be easier

Comment: I think I'll use a dapper for this.

Comment: why are you closing and opening connection every query? + you do not need to close connection while using `using` on it.

Comment: Should adding a list of items be a single transaction i.e. if you have a failure in adding one item the whole transaction should fail?